# Swift: How do you properly instantiate dates from selective date components?

Tags: swift, date, types, calendar

The following code is put in Swift Xcode playgrounds:

```
let day = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: .current, timeZone: .current, era: .none, year: 2020, month: 10, day: 1, hour: 1, minute: 1, second: 1, nanosecond: 1, weekday: .none, weekdayOrdinal: .none, quarter: .none, weekOfMonth: .none, weekOfYear: .none, yearForWeekOfYear: .none)) ?? Date()    
print(day)
```

Expected Output: 2020-10-26 01:01:01 +0000

Actual Output: 2020-09-30 18:01:01 +0000

Note: Date() of run is 26 October 2020

Is there a reason that the following code prints out a seemingly random date? Is this a swift bug (using XCode version 11.6 Beta)? Is there something wrong I am doing when instantiating dates with date components? How do I get the expected output?

Thanks

Comment: No this is correct, change your print to `print(day.description(with: .current))` to use current locale, that is same as the calendar

Comment: Not related to your question but you can simply omit the components that you are not using. Btw `DateComponents` have a `date` property `DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2020, month: 10, day: 1, hour: 1, minute: 1).date!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the `TimeZone` you are currently in (`.current`). If you want the output to be `2020-10-01 01:01:01 +0000`, you should create the `DateComponents` with UTC timezone like this:

```
let components = DateComponents(

    calendar: .current,
    timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC"),
    era: .none,
    year: 2020,
    month: 10,
    day: 1,
    hour: 1,
    minute: 1,
    second: 1,
    nanosecond: 1,
    weekday: .none,
    weekdayOrdinal: .none,
    quarter: .none,
    weekOfMonth: .none,
    weekOfYear: .none,
    yearForWeekOfYear: .none
)

let day = Calendar.current.date(from: components) ?? Date()
print(day)
```

Comment: OP said the expected output is Expected Output: 2020-10-26 01:01:01 +0000 which doesn't make any sense. Anyway the issue is not the input. The issue is that he is printing the date (UTC) instead of getting the date representation of the current timezone. Why would he specify the current timezone if he wants UTC?

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes. but he also expects the output to have `+0000` which refers to UTC timezone. Not sure if that is intentional.

Comment: He probably doesn’t even know what it means